# How to get value of option of a select element and use it in a calculation?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an example for this javascript textbook and it's a simple calculator. There are two input (number) tags where the user selects a number and a select tag with options for a modifier (see code).

```
<input type="number" value="2" id='num1'>
<select id="operation">
    <option>+</option>
    <option>-</option>
    <option>*</option>
    <option>/</option>
    <option>%</option>
</select>
<input type="number" value="2" id='num2'> =
<input type='text' readonly>
<br>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Do It!">
```

What I have to do is get the values of both the numbers and then calculate the operation based on which modifier is selected in the options.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(event) {
        var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var mod = document.getElementById("operation").selectedIndex;
    }
});
```

However, I don't understand how to do the calculation with the modifier. Would I need an if statement where it checks what value the mod has and then depending on that it does a certain calculation? Or is there a simpler way to just get the modifier and do a certain calculation that way?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this. The function will be called even if you just change the mathematical operator in the `select` box.

If you want to get the selected value from the `select` box, you have to use the `.value` prop, same as a normal input.

```js
function count() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var mod = document.getElementById("operation").value;
  document.getElementById('result').value = eval(num1 + mod + num2);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="2" id='num1'>
<select id="operation" onchange='count()'>
                <option>+</option>
                <option>-</option>
                <option>*</option>
                <option>/</option>
                <option>%</option>
            </select>
<input type="number" value="2" id='num2'> =
<input type='text' readonly id='result'><br>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Do It!" onclick='count()'>
```

Like Scott Marcus pointed, the `eval()` function is not really suggested to use anywhere in your project and **I'm aware** of that, but this is only for **learning purposes**.

Comment: Don't ever use `eval()`. It slows execution, changes scope and opens the door to XSS attacks. There is hardly ever a valid use case for it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Instead of downvoting, give another, working solution. And by the way - I'm sure that OP is just learning JS and he decided to do a simple calculator app. It's not for a **commercial** usage. I was doing the same thing, when I was starting with JS :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm still waiting for your reply.

Comment: I was working on my answer - that's why I didn't respond right away. The fact that the OP may be just learning JS is all the more reason not to suggest something like `eval`. It takes time and experience to understand why it is dangerous and how to avoid it. It is best to show the proper way to solve the problem instead of introducing a solution that should **never** be used.

Comment: @ScottMarcus OP asked for a simplier method than `conditions`. (if/switch). **Simplicity doesn't always come together with security**. Think about that.

Comment: Sorry, there is not going to be any valid argument you can make for showing a technique that is universally agreed upon as unacceptable. And, providing such an answer under the guise of "it's just for learning" makes it all the worse (full disclosure: I have been an IT instructor for 20 years).

Comment: @ScottMarcus The fact that you are IT instructor doesn't mean anything. You have just proposed him more complex but slower solution. I've provided him a quicker way, but less safe. But that's not a reason for a downvote.

Comment: Actually my solution will most likely execute faster than yours. If you don't understand why, then that's more evidence that you don't understand `eval()`. And, I would say that my 20+ years of daily education and instruction does happen to mean something. I would argue that your lack of experience and willful ignorance of the facts makes your argument mean nothing. Have a nice day. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform some `if/then` testing to see which value was selected and the proceed from there.

Also, don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, `onchange`) as they:

- create spaghetti code that is hard to read
- create anonymous global wrapper functions that modify the `this`
  binding
- don't follow W3C DOM Event Standards

Instead, follow standards and set up event handlers using **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

Lastly, it's not a great UI design to use a textbox (even a readonly one) for output that will not be interacted with directly. Instead, use a non-form HTML element (like a `<span>`) to house the result. You can always style the element to look anyway you want.

```js
// When the DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get references to DOM elements, not their values
  // This allows you to refrence the element over and over
  // without having to re-scan the DOM for it
  var select = document.getElementById("operation");
  var oper1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  var oper2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var btn = document.getElementById("button1");

  // Set up a click event handler for the button and the select:
  btn.addEventListener("click", count);
  select.addEventListener("change", count);

  function count() {
    var answer = null;
  
    // Convert the text values to numeric values
    var n1 = parseFloat(oper1.value);
    var n2 = parseFloat(oper2.value);

    // Determine the math operation needed and proceed accordingly
    switch (select.value){
      case "+":
        answer = n1 + n2;
        break;
      case "-":
        answer = n1 - n2;
        break;
      case "*":
        answer = n1 * n2;
        break;
      case "/":
        answer = n1 / n2;
        break;
      case "%":
        answer = n1 % n2;
        break;       
    }

    // Inject the answer into the HTML element
    result.textContent = answer; 
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="2" id='num1'>
<select id="operation">
                <option>+</option>
                <option>-</option>
                <option>*</option>
                <option>/</option>
                <option>%</option>
            </select>
<input type="number" value="2" id='num2'> =
<span id='result'></span><br>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Do It!">
```

Comment: I totally disagree about using inline event handling attributes. If you are using it wisely, you won't make a spaghetti code. Do you know anything about Angular? It uses inline events in HTML often. I'm sure that if it would be a bad habit, Google wouldn't introduce it.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason when I hit the button it doesn't print out the answer though.

Comment: @Kinduser You seem to want to just thumb your nose at standards and best practices. I'm not giving you my opinions here - I'm giving you well-established facts that are industry standards and best practices. Comparing inline HTML event attributes to Angular's use of them is anecdotal at best since Angular's code processes in a completely different way. In short, you can disagree all you want, but that doesn't make you right.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Good night.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I personally use [Riot.js](http://riotjs.com/) which also uses inline event handlers. However, unlike Angular is stays very close to W3 Spec. I agree with @KindUser that if used wisely, you won't end up with spaghetti code. `Eval()` is bad for production but a complex example like yours is just as bad for learning. The OP specifically asked, ". . . Or is there a simpler way to just get the modifier and do a certain calculation that way?" And the answer is yes– by using `eval()`. Not recommended, but yes—it is possible.

Comment: @JustinTaddei We're not talking about using libraries and frameworks that  require inline code. Comparisons to those types of things are false equivalencies. Those libraries process the handlers completely differently than how HTML event attributes do. Also, those libraries don't give you a choice, while you do have a choice of how to connect event handlers to native DOM elements in plain JS.

Comment: @JustinTaddei Also, my example is absolutely far from complex, it simply sets up event handlers, initializes some variables and performs `if/then` logic with a `switch`. That is JavaScript "101" stuff and, contrary to your opinion, perfect for learning proper techniques. I have over 20 years of highly successful experience that proves this without a doubt. Again, if you believe that `eval()` is simpler or performs better, then you are just misinformed about what actually happens when `eval()` is used.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This might seem simple to you and me, but you're forgetting something—we already know "JavaScript 101!" Blyter on the other hand probably doesn't and specifically asked if there was a way to use the operator itself. So with respect to the question, `eval()` is the only possible answer other than maybe `new Function()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus let's see which one gets more upvotes, shall we?

Comment: Up votes really don't change facts. Popular !== correct